# Delay/defer functionality in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

Trying to scrape a list of websites from jupyter notebook and below is the snippet

```
import requests as rqst
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllist = [ list of urls both http and https]

results = []
for i in urllist:
    print(i)
    pagecontent = rqst.get(i)
    if (pagecontent.status_code == 200):
        results.append(pagecontent)
```

Is there a way to make the execution to wait for few seconds/ until a status_code is available before moving to the next iteration?

Comment: The document says that the request object will wait for the response to come back. Do you see that the response is not `GET` completely and the status code isnt set right?

Comment: @shahkalpesh it too worked. i didn't tried it earlier, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `time.sleep()`.

```
import time

# Wait 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)
```